# Server 2008 damaged after .NET Framework 4.0 updates

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003-r2

I did an upgrade from Windows Server 2003 R2 to 2008. After quite some time (overnight) I was greeted with a Windows Server 2008 login box, I logged in and my services started successfully as did everything else, it even jumped straight on the network and had internet! Whilst I was checking some stuff out I got a .NET Framework 4.0 setup dialog box appear with no buttons, just informing me that it was updating the installation of .NET Framework 4.0 and would let me know when it's done.

After 10 minutes or so everything was running smoothly, several computers on my network had succesffully connected and were being issued with IP's and could access all network related features as normal, then .NET Framework 4.0 prompted me to reboot.. which I did. After this reboot nothing hardly works, I'd say around 30% of my services start and when I try to manually start the remaining I'm greeted with a 1053 error on each one. It no longer connects to the internet and some Windows dialog boxes just crash, like Network Center.

The problem is it's a live server and needs to be running ASAP! I've tried SFC /scannow and just get an error saying the Windows Resource cannot run, both in safe mode and normal. Safe mode allows it to connect to the network and more services to run, but still not 100%. Also now when restarting out of normal mode it gets stuck on "Stopping Group Policy..." message on shutdown and just hangs, this isn't the case when leaving safe mode.

Because it's a fresh upgrade I have no backups to restore to of Server 2008, it literally worked on initial boot then after installing the updates has not worked since.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: An upgrade from 2003 to 2008 on a live server...How did testing go before you decided to upgrade a production server?

Comment: Is your specific error "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."??  What's in the event logs?

Answer (score 0):

1053 sometimes happens when there is not enough space for acoount profile. Is there enough free space on target host, on AD server if exists.